# bat file to tick ar untick using proxy in PC

Tags: windows, proxy, internet-explorer, batch-file

It's that time of the day, leaving office and sit at home, turn on your laptop, you need to disable using the proxy on PC level from control panel > internet options > connections > proxy off... next morning, same thing at office, again go all this to enable it again... next find the inetcpl.cpl from Run to make sure to reach to that dialog easier tick/un-tick and say OK

it is annoying, i wanted to have bat file or reg key to make this one click instead of doing it all the time! nothing worked after too many searches and trying many scenarios..

I know browsers have proxy enable/disable addons, and work fine in Chrome and so, but for everything to work need to do it from Internet options so to have it on PC level...

Any working idea is welcome

Thanks

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Without words :-)

```
:: EnableProxy
@Echo off
set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "Val=ProxyEnable"
Set "Typ=REG_DWORD"
Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "0x1" /f
```

```
:: Disable Proxy
@Echo off
set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "Val=ProxyEnable"
Set "Typ=REG_DWORD"
Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "0x0" /f
```

```
:: ToggleProxy.cmd
@Echo off
set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "Val=ProxyEnable"
Set "Typ=REG_DWORD"
for /f "tokens=3" %%R in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v %Val% ^|find /i "%Val%"'
) do if "%%~R" equ "0x0" (
   Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "0x1" /f
) else (
   Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "0x0" /f
)
```

I wrote a similar one on StackOverflow to [toggle between two different Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41737778/6811411).

Comment: ok works only if run as administrator, windows 10. i tried first normally it was saying oepration successful but wasn't working .... treid with admin on seems working..  will check closer as well. thanks